# Camunda Engine behaviour with massive multi-instances processes and ready state

Tags: groovy, camunda, camunda-modeler

I wonder how Camunda manage multiple instances of a sub-process.
For **example** this BPMN:
[image]

Let's say multi-instances process would iterate on a big collection, 500 instances.

I have a function in a web app that call the endpoint to complete the `user common task`, and perform another call to camunda engine to get all tasks (on first API call callback). I am supposed to get a list of 500 sub-process user tasks (the ones generated by the multi-instances process).

> What if the `get tasks` call is performed before Camunda Engine successfully instantiated all sub-processes?

Do i get a partial list of task ?

> How to detect that main and sub processes are ready?

---

I don't really know if Camunda is able to manage this problematic by itself so I though of the following solution, knowing I only can use Modeler environment with Groovy to add code (Javascript as well, but the entire code parts already added are groovy):

- Use of a sub process throw event to catch in main process, then count and compare tasks ready with awaited tasks number for each signal emitted.

---

Thanks

Comment: Is this some spider sense tingling or do you have actual problems?  I don't know the answer for Camunda, but extrapolating from Activiti, you can specify a transaction manager (and you should, but most likely it's the default already) and then each step is either all or nothing. I'd be surprised if Camunda would handle this any differently.

Comment: @cfrick It is something I have to deal with, it works fine with a big amount of parallels sub processes, but I will have to instantiate many other main processes. And I wonder if Camunda would be able to deal with `n x 500` tasks to instantiate. I'll take a look at transaction managers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe likely spawn the tasks as parallel process (or 500 of them) and then got to a next step in which I signal or otherwise set a state that indicates the spawning is completed. I would further join the parallel processes all together again and have here a task signaling or otherwise setting a state that indicates all the parallel processes are done. See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/reference/bpmn20/gateways/parallel-gateway/. This way you can know exactly at what point (after spawning is done and before the join) you have a chance of getting your 500 spawned sub processes